# Version of Maven in Eclipse M2Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

Where I can see which version of Maven I run?

I installed Eclipse Kepler with "M2Eclipse Maven integration in Eclipse" (from repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M2E comes with an embedded version of maven.

You can see it under `Windows -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations`.

For Kepler, it is 3.0.4/1.4.1.20140328-1501.

However, you might consider installing your own version on your computer, add it in the preferences as maven installation and set it as default. You have more control over it that way and are not tied to a specific version that might change once you update your IDE.

Comment: I think you could (or should ;>) change "should" to "could" here. Why why should install standalone version? I think that may be useful for some people, but it's still some effort to learn how to do this, do and test. And if everything is working fine, it's not needed (althought it's worth noting that there is such possibility).